# Http redirect to https working with iis server and weblogic app server

Tags: iis-7, weblogic

I have two server

Server A: iis server
Server B: weblogic app server

iis accept the request (with http and https)
and forward the request to weblogic app server as **http** (using iis weblogic proxy)

what i try to do is to force iis to accept only https so when iis accept http request iis will repsonse to client with redirect to https (302 ststus)

how can i do it?
(i try to avoid do it in weblogic app server)

Comment: were you able to figure out this issue? @user986474

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and i couldn't get it resolved..

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution by using - url-rewrite.

url-rewrite is iis extension (iis 7.x and higher) it's let you do some action on requset (like redirect and more) by request filter (url pattern and more).

[url-rewrite extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

[iis http to https page](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

[iis http to https video](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)